# Telescopic trekking poles: clamp vs. screw system

Tags: gear, hiking, trekking, trekking-poles

I'm looking to get a new pair of trekking poles for my next trek as I find them an invaluable tool on longer hikes with higher pack load. It seems others and science agree [to some degree](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4470/are-trekking-poles-proven-to-be-helpful/7389#7389) at least, so I might even spend a bit of money and get me some expensive ones...

In the realm of telescopic trekking poles I have so fare seen two main systems to 'lock' the separate telescopic segments against one-another:

- **Clamp system**
  [image]
- **Screw system**
  [image]

**What are the benefits and drawbacks of the two systems?**

Comment: in my experience the main benefit of the screw system is that it breaks all the time

Comment: Clamps all the way. Everyone I know with the screw type have broken one. Look for the adjustable clamps, then you know they'll be good forever.

Comment: Ah, I searched for a while but somehow missed the duplicate. Sorry about that.